# Simplest way to get a Lisp "hello world" web application going

Tags: lisp, common-lisp

I want to write a Lisp web application just for fun. I found [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/451329/what-is-the-preferred-way-to-run-lisp-web-application) about Lisp web apps but all the answers seem so complicated. After looking into the links provided in the answers, the solutions seem *really* complicated.

If I just want a simple, "hello world" Lisp web app, is there not a simple way to do it?

Comment: What Lisp? Scheme, Common Lisp, Clojure? Latest has nice web framework called [Compojure](https://github.com/weavejester/compojure) (see README for very short example of usage).

Comment: I suppose I'm not terribly particular but Common Lisp is what I've used in the past.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This answer LOOKS complicated, but I think that getting a simple Lisp web app up and running is going to be easier than learning the other more awesome bits of Lisp anyway, so it's probably worth it.

There's a couple of really great Common Lisp books with intro-to-web-app chapters: [Practical Common Lisp](http://gigamonkeys.com/book/) and [Land of Lisp](http://landoflisp.com/).

There's a chapter in Land of Lisp which covers building a simple web server using sockets. It's pretty rudimentary, but I think would serve as a great starting point for a "hello world" type of Lisp app.

The chapter in Practical Common Lisp is at a higher level, and works with a full-fledged server called Allegro Serve. There are later chapters which build an MP3 streaming app.

Practical Common Lisp is available for free, here's the chapter of interest: http://gigamonkeys.com/book/practical-web-programming-with-allegroserve.html

I think both books are great resources for starting out with Common Lisp (as someone who's just starting out myself), although Land of Lisp is a bit more accessibile and more fun, although it does cover some interesting problems like lazy evaluation and searching game trees. Practical Common Lisp is more... practical, but that's not really a bad thing. It's aimed at professional programmers so its tone is just a little more serious.

One word of warning:

AFAIK Common Lisp doesn't have a really standard way of doing network programming, so this is one area of Lisp learning where you start to run into problems if you don't pick the same implementation as the book you happen to be reading.

Land of Lisp uses CLisp throughout, but you can use SBCL if you follow along with this blog post nearby: http://blog.ciaranbradley.com/crossing-the-streams-land-of-lisp-chapter-12-0

Practical Common Lisp uses Allegro Serve as I said, and I think there is a version of Allegro Lisp available from their site for use with the book. However, you can also use [Portable Allegro Serve](http://portableaserve.sourceforge.net/). Be careful if you are using Mac OS X and SBCL (as I am): SBCL's thread support is experimental on OS X, so if you go that route, the best bet is to install Ubuntu in a VM and then `apt-get install sbcl` and do your Allegro Serve programming in there, where SBCL threads are better supported. Maybe some CL wizards can suggest some other tips here. That's just what worked for me.

Answer (score 6):

For **CL-HTTP** one would load the server into Lisp and do:

```
(defun hello-world (url stream)
  (http:with-successful-response (stream :text)
    (princ "hello world" stream)))
```

Above is a **response function**. The response function has two arguments: an URL and a stream. The response function adds the usual response headers and says that it returns 'text'. Within this we just print a string to the output stream.

```
(http:export-url #u"/hello-world"
                 :computed
                 :response-function 'hello-world)
```

Above **exports an URL** that is merged with the default context (the default server name and port). The #u is a read macro to create URL objects. The URL is exported as :COMPUTED and thus needs a :RESPONSE-FUNCTION to compute the response. We pass in the function we defined above.

When a client sends a GET request with the URL to this server, it calls the response function for that URL and supplies an output stream.

Which then generates this content:

```
CL-USER 4 > (http:show-raw-url #u"/hello-world")

Status Code: 200 (OK)
Server Version: http/1.1
Date: Wed, 29 Dec 2010 23:39:52 GMT
Server: CL-HTTP/70.218 (LispWorks; 2.1.8)
Content-Type: text/plain; charset=ISO-8859-1
Transfer-Encoding: chunked

hello world
```

That's it.

Answer (score 3):

A simple Hello world should be with hunchentoot and cl-who.

```
(defparameter *httpd*
  (hunchentoot:start
   (make-instance 'hunchentoot:acceptor
                  :port 8080)))
(princ "Hunchentoot started on port ")
(princ *httpd-port*)
(terpri)

(hunchentoot:define-easy-handler (hello-world (:uri "/hello"))
    ()
  (with-html-output (*standard-output* nil :indent t)
       (:html
              (:head
                 (:title "Hello World"))
              (:body
                 (:p "Hello world!...")))))
```

For more information: http://weitz.de/hunchentoot/, http://zaries.wordpress.com/2010/11/09/lisp-web-server-from-scratch-using-hunchentoot-and-nginx/

To install hunchentoot, use quicklisp (it's the easiest).

```
  (ql:quickload :hunchentoot)
```

Answer (score 2):

[PLT Racket](http://racket-lang.org/) is a very fully-featured Scheme dialect that can do this.  They have a straightforward tutorial [here](http://docs.racket-lang.org/continue/index.html) in which they develop a small CMS, and some discussion about a Racket web server [here](http://docs.racket-lang.org/more/). If I were you, I'd try that.  Their "hello world" looks like this:

```
(define (start request)
 '(html
   (head (title "My Blog"))
   (body (h1 "Under construction"))))
```

See, it's not so bad!

(If Clojure counts as Lisp, of course, there are several web application frameworks in varying states of development for it as well.)

Answer (score 1):

[Here](http://sites.google.com/site/sabraonthehill/home/exploring-quicklisp-packages) is a recent article on building a simple webapp in Common Lisp.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at "[Making a small Lisp project with quickproject and Quicklisp](http://xach.livejournal.com/278047.html)" for an example slightly more complicated than "Hello World".

Answer (score 0):

Here's a [blog post](http://postabon.posterous.com/a-simple-lisp-webapp-for-beginners) that sets up SBCL and Hunchentoot to serve a hello-world page.

I won't claim it's the best way to set up a web app but it is pretty straightforward.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I'm not completely sure what you mean by "web app". When I bang together a dynamic site, I usually work in a CGI mindset. 
Here's a link to a CGI setup for Common Lisp http://www.cl-user.net/asp/jf8v/sdataQvStnw8XWwrFDQ3xCR8X8yBX8yBXnMq=/sdataQu3F$sSHnB==

For a reason I'm not yet sure of, most Lisp web work seems to center around a web server built in Lisp instead of having Apache or IIS call out into the Lisp software to parse the .lisp file.

Comment: Yeah, I don't get that either. Why not use Apache?

Comment: Most Lisps, especially Common Lisp implementations, are image based and compiled. Loading the image, compiling the code and then linking it into the image is not something that should be done for every request. And since you need a persistent process anyway, it might just as well be a web server that can be proxied to using standard functionality.